# Display all records of a table using PL/SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

There is a table named `Student(Roll, Name, Sub1, Sub2, Sub3)`. 
I want to write a procedure that will print Roll, Name and the average marks obtained by all the students. But I don't know how to make the procedure read the rows one by one and perform the operation on each row iteratively.

Comment: what kind of DB do you have ?, for your case it is recommended to create a function rather than a procedure, for looping in SQL server follow this link, :  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6148/sql-server-loop-through-table-rows-without-cursor/

Comment: @wahyu, PL/SQL is a procedural extension to Oracle's SQL, so - that's Oracle.

Comment: I hope that this is an assignment, because no one will do this in production applications: 1) loop is inappropriate construct for SQL calculations, 2) "print" is pointless because application will not handle this without specific setup

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, it is Oracle SQL.

Comment: @astentx yes. It is actually assignment.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use nested loops (one for rolls, and one for students within that roll). Display data using `dbms_output.put_line` calls.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table student (roll, name, sub1, sub2, sub3) as
  2  select 1, 'Scott', 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  3  select 1, 'Tiger', 4, 5, 2 from dual union all
  4  select 2, 'King' , 3, 4, 2 from dual;

Table created.
```

Read comments within code:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_sum number;   -- sum of all marks
  3    l_cnt number;   -- number of studnents per roll
  4    l_avg number;   -- average mark per roll
  5  begin
  6    for cur_r in (select distinct roll from student order by roll)
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line('Roll ' || cur_r.roll ||' ------------------------------');
  9
 10      -- initialize variables for each roll
 11      l_sum := 0;
 12      l_cnt := 0;
 13      for cur_s in (select name, sub1 + sub2 + sub3 as sub
 14                    from student
 15                    where roll = cur_r.roll
 16                    order by name
 17                   )
 18      loop
 19        -- total sum of marks per all students within that roll
 20        l_sum := l_sum + cur_s.sub;
 21        l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 22
 23        -- This is one student and their average
 24        dbms_output.put_line('Student: ' || cur_s.name ||', their average mark = '
 25          || round(cur_s.sub / 3, 1));
 26      end loop;
 27      -- divide by 3 as there are 3 subjects per student
 28      l_avg := round(l_sum / 3 / l_cnt, 1);
 29
 30      -- This is roll's average
 31      dbms_output.put_line('Roll ' || cur_r.roll ||' average mark = '
 32        || l_avg);
 33    end loop;
 34  end;
 35  /
```

Result:

```
Roll 1 ------------------------------
Student: Scott, their average mark = 2
Student: Tiger, their average mark = 3.7
Roll 1 average mark = 2.8
Roll 2 ------------------------------
Student: King, their average mark = 3
Roll 2 average mark = 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now that you know *how*, improve it and make it pretty.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`, depending on how particular the OP is about the output format.